# InflateException just in release mode

Tags: android

recently I Used from uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy library to set font on my views. In debug mode, everything is OK but in release mode, by clicking on any activitys, it has InflateException. I need some help to handle it. .
This is My ProGuard rules:

```
    -keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class android.**
-dontwarn android.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

**and this is Android Studio Log:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.matingdz.InsDLFreeGooglePlay, PID: 4592
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.matingdz.InsDLFreeGooglePlay/com.matingdz.InsDLFreeGooglePlay.DlStory}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.a()' on a null object reference
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setBackgroundDrawable(Unknown Source:5)
                      at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:20326)
                      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5200)
                      at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:824)
                      at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:172)
                      at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:147)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(Unknown Source:4)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(Unknown Source:3)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.a(Unknown Source:284)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(Unknown Source:51)
                      at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView(Unknown Source:4)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                      at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(Unknown Source:3)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.b(Unknown Source:23)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(Unknown Source:4)
                      at com.matingdz.InsDLFreeGooglePlay.DlStory.onCreate(Unknown Source:7)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this rule to your Proguard rules file:

```
-keepclassmembernames class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

I'm not sure if it is the best solution, but it did the trick for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Adding an explanation on what that rule does would help to improve your answer.